# After upgrade, some user can not install from Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

Well I have android aplication and normally my apps are working good, yesterday (15,06,2014) I have made update and than some user starts to sent me a mail and they said

> "we can not install app from google play store.

and some another user said:

> we are clicking upgrade and they are seeing a problem starts with "S-3".

I didnt change anything in manifest file (such as sdk version). And Also I have tried to install some phone near me and they are working properly. Actually I didnt understand What is going on.

Comment: Probably Google Play store having some backend issues.

Comment: Whats that "backend issue". I see some people all over the world has same problem for today. Look here http://downdetector.com/status/google-play

Comment: Not sure what the backend issue is, but there are times when the Google Play store can go down, or not serve specific regions correctly.